# When creating @OneToOne throws error failed to retrieve ResultSet

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, hibernate, jpa

There are two classes `Cook` and `User`. Accordingly, there are two tables! All users are stored in the `User` table, and `Cook` displays them through with `JSon` to the @OneToOne connection. The `User` class is also the parent. It seems to have done everything right. On guides and documentation, but I can’t understand what the problem is. Why does he swear at a column of a table that already exists !!

Class `USER`:

```java
package com.tinychiefdelights.model;

import lombok.Data;

import javax.persistence.*;

@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "pg_user", schema = "public")
public class User {

    public User(){ // Пустой конструктор для Hibernate

    }

    public User(String name, String lastName, String role,
                String login, String password){ // Базовый конструктор для дочерних классов

        this.name = name;
        this.lastName = lastName;
        this.role = role;
        this.login = login;
        this.password = password;
    }

    // Поля
    @Column(name = "id")
    private @Id @GeneratedValue Long id;

    @Column(name = "login")
    private String login;

    @Column(name = "password")
    private String password;

    @Column(name = "role")
    private String role;
    //здесь должен быть enum

    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;

    @Column(name = "last_name")
    private String lastName;
}
```

Class `Cook`:

```java
package com.tinychiefdelights.model;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonBackReference;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonManagedReference;
import com.tinychiefdelights.service.CookType;
import lombok.Data;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.util.List;

@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "cook", schema = "public")
public class Cook {


    public Cook(){ // Пустой конструктор для Hibernate

    }


    // Поля
    private @Id @GeneratedValue Long id;

    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_id") // Join without Cook in User
    private User user;

//    private CookType cookType;

    @Column(name = "rating")
    private float rating;

    @Column(name = "cook_status")
    private boolean cookStatus;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinTable(
            name = "cook_review",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "review_id"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "cook_id")) // Удалишь эту строку - получишь ошибочек
    @JsonManagedReference // Таким образом я предотвратил рекурсию
    private List<Review> reviewList;

    @Column(name = "about_cook")
    private String aboutCook;

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinTable(
            name = "cook_dish",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "dish_id"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "cook_id"))
    @JsonManagedReference // Таким образом я предотвратил рекурсию
    private  List<Dish> dish;

    // Поля name, lastName, login, password наследуются от класса User;
}
```

[image]

```java
2020-04-11 13:04:34.147 ERROR 12668 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : ERROR: row user0_.user_id doesnt exist
  Позиция: 615
2020-04-11 13:04:34.158  INFO 12668 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.h.e.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener  : HHH000327: Error performing load command

org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLStateConversionDelegate.convert(SQLStateConversionDelegate.java:103) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.12.Final.jar:5.4.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:42) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.12.Final.jar:5.4.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:113) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.12.Final.jar:5.4.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:99) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.12.Final.jar:5.4.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.extract(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:67) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.12.Final.jar:5.4.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.internal.AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.getResultSet(AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.java:390) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.12.Final.jar:5.4.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.internal.AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.executeQueryStatement(AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.java:163) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.12.Final.jar:5.4.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.internal.AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.executeLoad(AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.java:104) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.12.Final.jar:5.4.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.entity.plan.AbstractLoadPlanBasedEntityLoader.load(AbstractLoadPlanBasedEntityLoader.java:223) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.12.Final.jar:5.4.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.doLoad(AbstractEntityPersister.java:4396) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.12.Final.jar:5.4.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.load(AbstractEntityPersister.java:4386) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.12.Final.jar:5.4.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.loadFromDatasource(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:569) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.12.Final.jar:5.4.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.doLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:537) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.12.Final.jar:5.4.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.load(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:208) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.12.Final.jar:5.4.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.proxyOrLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:332) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.12.Final.jar:5.4.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.doOnLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:108) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.12.Final.jar:5.4.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.onLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:74) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.12.Final.jar:5.4.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.service.internal.EventListenerGroupImpl.fireEventOnEachListener(EventListenerGroupImpl.java:113) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.12.Final.jar:5.4.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.fireLoadNoChecks(SessionImpl.java:1176) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.12.Final.jar:5.4.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.internalLoad(SessionImpl.java:1041) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.12.Final.jar:5.4.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.type.EntityType.resolveIdentifier(EntityType.java:687) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.12.Final.jar:5.4.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.type.EntityType.resolve(EntityType.java:464) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.12.Final.jar:5.4.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.type.ManyToOneType.resolve(ManyToOneType.java:240) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.12.Final.jar:5.4.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.TwoPhaseLoad.doInitializeEntity(TwoPhaseLoad.java:231) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.12.Final.jar:5.4.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.TwoPhaseLoad.initializeEntity(TwoPhaseLoad.java:162) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.12.Final.jar:5.4.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.initializeEntitiesAndCollections(Loader.java:1179) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.12.Final.jar:5.4.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.processResultSet(Loader.java:1028) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.12.Final.jar:5.4.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:964) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.12.Final.jar:5.4.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:354) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.12.Final.jar:5.4.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2838) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.12.Final.jar:5.4.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2820) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.12.Final.jar:5.4.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2652) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.12.Final.jar:5.4.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2647) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.12.Final.jar:5.4.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.hql.QueryLoader.list(QueryLoader.java:506) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.12.Final.jar:5.4.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.list(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:396) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.12.Final.jar:5.4.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.performList(HQLQueryPlan.java:219) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.12.Final.jar:5.4.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1404) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.12.Final.jar:5.4.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.doList(AbstractProducedQuery.java:1562) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.12.Final.jar:5.4.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.list(AbstractProducedQuery.java:1530) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.12.Final.jar:5.4.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.query.Query.getResultList(Query.java:165) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.12.Final.jar:5.4.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.query.criteria.internal.compile.CriteriaQueryTypeQueryAdapter.getResultList(CriteriaQueryTypeQueryAdapter.java:76) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.12.Final.jar:5.4.12.Final]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository.findAll(SimpleJpaRepository.java:355) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.2.5.RELEASE.jar:2.2.5.RELEASE]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryComposition$RepositoryFragments.invoke(RepositoryComposition.java:371) ~[spring-data-commons-2.2.5.RELEASE.jar:2.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryComposition.invoke(RepositoryComposition.java:204) ~[spring-data-commons-2.2.5.RELEASE.jar:2.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$ImplementationMethodExecutionInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:657) ~[spring-data-commons-2.2.5.RELEASE.jar:2.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:621) ~[spring-data-commons-2.2.5.RELEASE.jar:2.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:605) ~[spring-data-commons-2.2.5.RELEASE.jar:2.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.projection.DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.java:80) ~[spring-data-commons-2.2.5.RELEASE.jar:2.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:366) ~[spring-tx-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:99) ~[spring-tx-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:139) ~[spring-tx-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodInterceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:178) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.2.5.RELEASE.jar:2.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:95) ~[spring-aop-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:212) ~[spring-aop-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy113.findAll(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at com.tinychiefdelights.controller.CookController.all(CookController.java:22) ~[main/:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:190) ~[spring-web-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:138) ~[spring-web-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:106) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:879) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:793) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1040) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:943) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:898) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:634) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.31.jar:9.0.31]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.31.jar:9.0.31]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.31.jar:9.0.31]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.31.jar:9.0.31]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-9.0.31.jar:9.0.31]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.31.jar:9.0.31]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.31.jar:9.0.31]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100) ~[spring-web-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.31.jar:9.0.31]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.31.jar:9.0.31]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93) ~[spring-web-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.31.jar:9.0.31]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.31.jar:9.0.31]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201) ~[spring-web-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.31.jar:9.0.31]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.31.jar:9.0.31]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.31.jar:9.0.31]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.31.jar:9.0.31]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:541) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.31.jar:9.0.31]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.31.jar:9.0.31]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.31.jar:9.0.31]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.31.jar:9.0.31]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.31.jar:9.0.31]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:367) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.31.jar:9.0.31]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.31.jar:9.0.31]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:868) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.31.jar:9.0.31]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1639) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.31.jar:9.0.31]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.31.jar:9.0.31]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628) ~[na:na]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.31.jar:9.0.31]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:835) ~[na:na]
```

Comment: Could you please show the code snippet that rise this exception?

Comment: and which piece of code can show this? I don’t know what it is! can throw off the controller?

Comment: Debugging will help to find out it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hibernate try to find the column user_id in the user table, as it says in your error

```
ERROR: row user0_.user_id doesnt exist
```

You have to add also the one to one relation also in User entity

```
@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "pg_user", schema = "public")
public class User {

    // other fields

    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "user")
    private Cook cook;

    // ...
}
```

Comment: I guess the error message is the same ERROR: row user0_.user_id doesnt exist ?

Comment: Try to add the one to one relation also in User entity @OneToOne(mappedBy = "user")
    private Cook cook;